# how can set parameter values for params string[] parameter

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, url, model-view-controller

I am required to produce the following address

```
http://example.com/Content/Details?cid=34&query=%D8%AA%D8%AD&positions%5B0%5D=true&positions%5B0%5D=false&positions%5B1%5D=false&positions%5B2%5D=false
```

this url after decode is :

```
  http://example.com/Content/Details?cid=32&query=تحلیل&positions[0]=true&positions[0]=false&positions[1]=false&positions[2]=false
```

My action method contains the following parameters

```
public ActionResult Details(
string cid, string query,  int? page, int id = 0, params string[]      positions)
{

 if(positions != null)
    {
      ViewBag.Title = positions[0];
      ViewBag.Description = positions[1];
      ViewBag.KeyWord = positions[2];

     }
}
```

But when I set the parameters required for the positions parameter I get an error :

In fact i cant  use positions[0] , positions[1] and positions[2] !!!

my cshtml page :

```
@{ title &nbsp;
    @Html.CheckBox("positions[0]", ViewBag.Title as string) &nbsp;

    description
    @Html.CheckBox("positions[1]", ViewBag.Description as string) &nbsp;

   keyword 
    @Html.CheckBox("positions[2]", ViewBag.KeyWord as string) &nbsp;
```

}

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Details", new {cid = ViewBag.currentFilter, query= ViewBag.currentSearchString , positions[0]=ViewBag.title , positions[1]=ViewBag.Description ,position[2]=ViewBag.KeyWord,page }))
```

how can i set values for positions parameter in cshtml page ?

How can i set position[0] ,positions[2] and positions[3] ... i want know this just

the rest of my code is correct

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read them in your controller and set them in ViewBag or ViewData:

```
ViewData["positons_0"] = Request.QueryString["positions[0]"];
ViewData["positons_1"] = Request.QueryString["positions[1]"];
// etc ...
```

Then you will be able to use them in your view also.

But I would suggest that you remove the square brackets from your querystring if possible. These are reserverd characters for IP v6 address literals (see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2)) and this is why you cannot use them in MVC. Your url should be:

```
http://example.com/Content/Details?cid=32&query=تحلیل&positions=true&positions=false&positions=false&positions=false
```

In this way you will be able to use it in both your controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(string cid, string query,  int? page, int id = 0, string[] positions)
{ 
    // ....
}
```

... and view:

```
@foreach(string position in Model.positions) // example
{ 
    // ....
}
```